# Socket.io website not accessible

Tags: socket.io

Trying to read the socket.io complete documentation for adding in node.js project but website seems down. I have checked the DNS propagation aswell. Any other way to check the documentation?

[image]

Comment: any reason for vote down ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Documentation on their site is useless, had a lot of headache with it. I finally managed to learned it, without their docs. You can read this guide before going further:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/socket.io/index.htm